# C# initialize variable after checking a condition

Tags: c#, variables

I need to use a variable initialized only after checking a condition.
I get the error:

> Use of unassigned local variable

Does not the compile check if the conditions are the same?
This is my code. How can I solve it?

```
Web web;
if (myCondition){
    //heavy operation
    web = site.openWeb();
}

for ( n loop)
{
    //do stuff
    if (myCondition){
        //use web
    }
}

if (myCondition){
    web.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: No; what if the value of `myCondition` changes?

Comment: Instead of "Web web;", use "Web web = null;", this will have the variable initialized properly

Comment: I am sure that it wont change.

Comment: Wait, it wont change inside the method. But it can change in different method execution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply set it to null to make sure it is initialized at all:

```
Web web = null;
```

And then, when disposing, better check that variable is not null, to make sure you dispose always when necessary:

```
if (web != null){
    web.Dispose();
}
```

Also note that you won't all `Dispose` if an exception is thrown in the loop. So you might want to wrap it all in try/finally.

But as it already came that far - have you considered [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks, I used Using inside the for but on each loop the new and dispose operation were performed.

Comment: Well, `using` should be used (sorry) when the disposable object is created. So I suggest you to revisit code a little, so that all creations of disposable objects are wrapped in using, or in plain try/finally

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Web web =  null;
if (myCondition)
{
    //heavy operation
    web = site.openWeb();
}

for ( n loop)
{
    //do stuff
    if (myCondition)
    {
        //use web
    }
}

if (myCondition)
{
    web.Dispose()
}
```